# WebApi Route with Nested Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is it possible to MapHttpRoute to a nested ApiController class?  If yes, what RouteTemplate achieves it?

Example nested controller:

```
public class whatever
{
    public class NestedController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public object five()
        {
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using

```
GET ApiRoute/whatever+nested/five
```

as typeof(whatever.NestedController) reports whatever+NestedController but I get

> No type was found that matches the controller

Comment: Did you try `GET ApiRoute/nested/five` (without the 'whatever')?

Comment: Yes, same "no type found...." response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the routing engine looks for concrete classes only.  It doesn't matter which assembly they're in or which namespace they're in but they can't be nested in another class and they can't be abstract.

One benefit (although it's a stretch) is this is that you can "hide" controllers in a DLL and activate them in a Web App like this:

DLL:

```
public class Wrapper { public class MyController : ApiController { /*code goes here*/ } }
```

Web App:

```
public class MyController : Wrapper.MyController { }
```

All that said, I don't recommend it.  It's best to use things as designed because you risk opening a security hole or making the application fragile to API updates.